# Modern Vector implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, vectors

Please give me some feedback on my attempt at a vector.  I wanted this to be the lowest level concept of a vector that I'm using, so I'm primarily concerned with speed, and I would build wrappers afterward for safety when its needed. This is why I'm not using the copy and swap idiom for the copy ctor.  Anyway please critique and give explanations for changes where it can be improved for my goal.

vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    typedef const T* const_iterator;

    Vector();
    Vector(unsigned int size);
    Vector(unsigned int size, const T& initial);
    Vector(const Vector<T>& v);
    Vector(Vector<T> && v);
    ~Vector();

    Vector<T>& operator =(Vector<T> const& v);
    Vector<T>& operator =(Vector<T> && v); // move assignment

    inline unsigned int capacity() const { return m_capacity; }
    inline unsigned int size() const { return m_size; }
    inline bool empty() const { return m_size == 0; }
    inline iterator begin() { return buff; }
    inline iterator end() { return buff + (m_size - 1) * sizeof(T); }
    inline const_iterator c_begin() { return buff; }
    inline const_iterator c_end() { return buff + (m_size - 1) * sizeof(T); }
    T& front();
    T& back();
    void pushBack(const T& val);
    void popBack();

    void reserve(unsigned int capacity);
    void resize(unsigned int size);

    T& operator [](unsigned int index);
    void clear();

private:
    unsigned int m_capacity;
    unsigned int m_size;
    unsigned int Log;
    T* buff;

    void swap(Vector<T> & v);
};

#endif
```

vector.cpp:

```
#include "vector.h"
#include <cmath> //for Log

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector() : 
    m_capacity(0),
    m_size(0),
    Log(0),
    buff(nullptr) {}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int size) : //an argument of 0 leads to a capacity value of 1, distinct from the default ctor
    m_size(size), 
    Log(ceil(log((double)size) / log(2.0))), 
    m_capacity(1 << Log), 
    buff(size ? new T[m_capacity] : nullptr) {}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int size, const T& initial) :
    m_size(size), 
    Log(ceil(log((double)size) / log(2.0))), 
    m_capacity(1 << Log), 
    buff(size ? new T[m_capacity] : nullptr)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        //using placement new to place each element of v[i] in our already allocated buffer
        new(buffer + i) T(initial);
    }
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T> const& v) :
    m_capacity(v.capacity()), 
    m_size(v.size()), 
    Log(v.Log),  
    buff(m_size ? new T[m_capacity] : nullptr)
{
    std::copy(v.buff, v.buff + v.m_size, buff); //std::copy is better than loops if we have both arrays
    //for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        //new(buffer + sizeof(T)*i) T(v[i]);
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T> && v)
    : m_size(0),
    m_capacity(0),
    buff(nullptr),
    Log(0)
{
    swap(v);
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator =(Vector<T> const& v)
// //not strong exception, but will write a wrapper that makes it strong exception; lowest level -> fastest
{
    delete[] buff;
    buff = nullptr;
    buff = v.m_capacity ? new T[v.m_capacity * sizeof(T)] : nullptr;
    m_size = v.m_size;
    m_capacity = v.m_capacity;
    Log = v.Log;
    std::copy(v.buff, v.buff + m_size-1, buff);
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator =(Vector<T> && v)
{
    delete[] buff; //prep this
    m_size = 0;
    buff = nullptr;
    m_capacity = 0;
    Log = 0;

    swap(v);

    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete[] buff;
    buff = nullptr;
    m_size = 0;
    m_capacity = 0;
    Log = 0;
}

template<typename T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](unsigned int index)
{
    return buff[index];
}

template<typename T>
T& Vector<T>::front()
{
    return buff[0];
}

template<typename T>
T& Vector<T>::back()
{
    return buff[m_size - 1];
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::reserve(unsigned int capac)
{
    T* newbuff = new T[capac];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        newbuff[i] = buff[i];

    m_capacity = capac;
    delete[] buff;
    buff = newbuff;
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::resize(unsigned int size)
{
    Log = ceil(log((double)size) / log(2.0));
    reserve(1 << Log);
    m_size = size;
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::pushBack(const T& val)
{
    if (m_size >= m_capacity)
    {
        reserve(1 << Log++);
    }

    buff[m_size++] = val;
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::popBack()
{
    (reinterpret_cast<T*>(buff)[m_size-- - 1]).~T();
}

template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        (reinterpret_cast<T*>(buff)[i]).~T();

    m_size = 0;
    m_capacity = 0;
    Log = 0;
    buff = 0;
}

template<typename  T>
void Vector<T>::swap(Vector<T> & v)
{
    std::swap(m_size, v.m_size);
    std::swap(m_capacity, v.m_capacity);
    std::swap(buff, v.buff);
    std::swap(Log, v.Log);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not simply using `std::vector`?

Comment: If this is meant to be [tag:reinventing-the-wheel], you should add that tag (and consider using matching names such as `push_back` and `cbegin`).

Comment: `inline` as a keyword for functions defined in class is useless because these functions get `inline` automatic.

Comment: I don't think the code as posted was actually ready for a review. Please test your code before submitting it here.

Comment: Why do you think that copy-and-swap idiom might reduce the speed?

Comment: Have a read of the four articles I wrote about creating a vector in C++: [Loki Astari Vector](http://lokiastari.com/series/) Lots of tips to help.

Comment: `vector` [tag:reinventing-the-wheel] is pretty common. See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breinventing-the-wheel%5D+vector) for a bunch of search results.

Comment: [`std::log2()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2) exists

Answer (score 22):

## Memory management

- `new T[m_capacity]` default-constructs `m_capacity` objects of type `T` in there.

  This might hurt performance a lot if `T`s default constructor is not trivial, and even then it still isn't necessary.

  Even worse, in `pushBack` a new `T` object gets copy constructed in the place of the already existing one (if `m_size < m_capacity`), without properly deleting it. This might cause an abundance of errors, especially if `T`s destructor is not trivial (e.g. it would leak memory).

  Consider using `std::aligned_storage` for storing the objects instead.
- The implementation leaks memory if an exception is thrown during any of the member functions which call `new` (e.g. due to no being able to allocate new memory). Using `std::unique_ptr` helps preventing those leaks.
- `clear` leaks memory (no call to `delete[]`).
- Some member functions (see below) set `m_capacity`, `Log` and/or `m_size` to unexpected values, which in turn can cause wrong allocations and/or out of bounds memory accesses in other places.

  - `reserve` accesses out of bounds memory if `capac < m_size` due to `newbuff[i]` being out of bounds.
  - For any given `m_capacity`, the first call to `pushBack` where `m_size >= m_capacity` doesn't allocate bigger space (`Log` gets increased **after** the call to `reserve` in `reserve(1 << Log++)`).

    This means `Log` is out of sync from `m_capacity`, `buff[m_size++]` is out of bounds and `m_size > m_capacity` after the call.
  - The constructors taking a `size` parameter initialize `m_capacity` before `Log` (due to member definition order inside the class), but refer to the uninitialized value of `Log` for doing so. This sets `m_capacity` to a wrong value, and thus allocates a wrong amount of memory for `buff` (if `size > 0`).
- `pushBack` has a potential use-after-free error: If `val` refers to an element inside this `Vector` and `Vector` needs to reallocate, `val` will dangle when the new object gets copy constructed.
- The copy assignment operator deletes `buff` without checking whether `this == &v`. If that condition is true, it deleted `v.buff` (which it then will try to index in order to populate the newly allocated `buff`).

  - Also, that newly allocated `buff` is too large by a factor of `sizeof(T)`.

> You might want to look into using `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` for `buff`. While this doesn't fix out of bounds memory access, it will help with some of the other issues.

## Usage with standard algorithms

- The name changes of `push_back`, `pop_back`, `cbegin` and `cend` make this container unusable for standard algorithms.
- `begin` and `end` should provide a `const` overload, so they can be called on a `const Vector<T>&`.
- Similarly, `cbegin` and `cend` should be declared `const`.
- Also, `push_front`, `pop_front`, `emplace`, `emplace_back`, `emplace_front`, `remove`, `insert` and all the reverse iterator variants are missing.

## Naming

- The style of names for member variables is inconsistent: `m_size`/`m_capacity`, `buff` and `Log`. Choose one and stay consistent!

## Class design

- There is no way to handle types that have no default or no copy constructor. Please provide an overload on `push_back(T&&)` to accept non-copyable types, and `emplace_front`/`emplace_back` methods to construct `T` objects for types that have neither a copy nor a move constructor. (The `emplace`-type methods can also provide performance benefits by reducing copy/move constructions.)
- A `const Vector<T>&` has no way to access elements inside it. Please provide `const` overloads for `front`, `back` and `operator[]`.
- `Vector<T>::swap` should likely be `public`.
- `Vector<T>` isn't copyable unless `T` itself is. Thus, the copy constructor and copy assignment operator should be `delete`d for those cases.
- Why force the buffer to a size that is a power of 2? If I specify an exact size in the constructor (or via `reserve`/`resize`), I'd expect the `Vector` to have exactly that size (and not waste additional memory).
- No member functions give any exception specification. This prevents certain kinds of optimization. Especially the move constructor, move assignment operator and destructor should be `noexcept`.

## Other issues

- Why `reinterpret_cast<T*>(buff)`? `buff` is already of type `T*`.
- `inline` actually doesn't do anything in this implementation.
- `clear()` doesn't call destructors for objects between `m_size` and `m_capacity`. (Then again, it doesn't `delete[] buff`, which would fix that.)
- Prefer `{}` over `()` for initialization. While there is no instance of the most vexing parse in this code, it always helps to be mindful.
- As @TobySpeigh mentions, please put all code into the header file, as all code for templates needs to be accessible where instantiated. (Currently, one would have to use `#include "vector.cpp"`, which is surprising.)
- Iterators returned by `end()` and `cend()` are expected to point **one** element after the last one (i.e. `buff + m_size`). Currently, they point wildly out of bounds (`buff + (m_size - 1) * sizeof(T)`).
- Sometimes `std::copy` is used for copying, sometimes a raw `for` loop. This is inconsistent.

  - In some of those cases, they could be replaced by a range-based `std::move` (if `T` is nothrow movable).
  - In some cases, the last element isn't copied due to bound miscalculations.

## Performance

- No member function gives any exception specification. This might impede performance.
- Why use floating point math for `Log`? (And why use `Log` at all?)
- Try to `std::move` objects if possible. This can be asserted with template meta programming.
- You might consider using `realloc` for reallocations if `T` is trivially copyable.
- And as always, if performance is important, measure it! Doing premature optimization (especially at the cost of readability or extensibility) is bad.

  Also, be sure your code is working correctly before trying to optimize. It doesn't matter if it is really fast if it produces the wrong result!

Comment: Many programmers prefer power-of-two heap allocations so as to minimize heap fragmentation. It also gets you O(log n) reallocation when repeatedly inserting.

Comment: @Davislor: Every constant growth factor provides \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$ reallocations upon insertion. And minimizing head fragmentation might be a good general goal, but not wasting memory if the user explicitly specifies their size requirements should be weighed higher IMHO.

Comment: @hoffmale Every constant growth factor does, yes. Allocating only as much memory as you need, though, might need a billion allocations if you add a billion elements one-by-one. The counterargument to wasting memory was: if you do a lot of resizing or deallocation of small objects, you might in practice end up with lots of heap blocks that are too small to use, but that take a long time to search.

Comment: @hoffmale Added a section to my answer about that.

Comment: @Davislor: The part about "minimizing memory usage" was only for the case in which the user explicitly states their size requirements (i.e. specifies a size in the constructor or calls `resize`/`reserve`). In the general case, using a growth factor and some heuristic for size is fine.

Comment: @hoffmale That makes more sense. Thanks for clarifying. The concern is still that you might take up 62 bytes of a 64-byte block, I think, and leave a bunch of holes in the heap too small to be useful.

Comment: @Davislor Power of two heap allocations lead to the walking vector problem if you have one growing vector; no amount of previously freed vector buffers can fit your new memory request.  Any sub power of 2 can avoid this, where after some number K iterations the previously deallocated K buffers can be used for the K+2nd exponential growth.

Comment: Hoff, it might be worth noting that there is no standard compliant portable way to fully implement vector due to "bugs" in how the standard defines contiguous memory and arrays and aliasing issues.

Comment: @Yakk: Could give give some more information about that? I'd like to learn more :) Also, to prevent a walking vector, the growth factor needs to be below the golden ratio (1.9 wouldn't work)

Comment: @hoffmale Yes, that is right.  Basically, it boils down to, even if I know that A and B are next to placement-new'd next to each other in memory, `(&A)+1` is not a legal way to get `B`'s address.  But if they are elements *directly* in an array, it is.  And you cannot resize arrays in C++, just create new ones of specific sizes.

Answer (score 12):

A few things you can improve upon:

### Use more of `<algorithm>` and `<memory>`

Raw loops are verbose and unreadable. Use algorithms whenever you can -I've just noticed that you did it in some cases, but left the raw loops in others (cf `reserve`). You also seem not to know `std::uninitialized_fill`, which does exactly what you do manually in your third constructor, or `std::destroy` that's here to achieve what you do in `clear` (`std::destroy_at` is for individual elements, as in `popBack`).

### Factorize constructors

Constructors can call other constructors. It avoids some copy-pasting. So, given:

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int size) : //an argument of 0 leads to a     capacity value of 1, distinct from the default ctor
    m_size(size), 
    Log(ceil(log((double)size) / log(2.0))), 
    m_capacity(1 << Log), 
    buff(size ? new T[m_capacity] : nullptr) {}
```

you can have:

```
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned size, const T& value) : Vector(size) {
    std::copy(buffer, buffer+size, value); 
}
```

### Simplify your destructor

You don't need to reset all member variables in your destructor, since you can't use it after anyway.

Answer (score 11):

There is a bug in `pushBack`, you need to take into account the case where you call it on an existing member of the array.

For example in the code

```
Vector<int> v(1,0);
v.pushBack(v[0]);
```

`pushBack` will first resize the array, invalidating the reference to `v[0]`. It will then attempt to insert that invalid reference in the new array.

Comment: Wow, totally overlooked that one with all the other memory management issues!

Comment: Actually, this behavior is undefined in this specific case. `Vector<int> v(1, 0)` initializes `m_capacity` wrong, thus `v.pushBack(v[0])` might not actually reallocate.

Answer (score 10):

### Use the well-known names for methods

`c_begin` and `c_end` are so close to the standard-container `cbegin` and `cend` that users will forever curse you.  Likewise for `pushBack` and `popBack` (instead of the usual `push_back` and `pop_back`).

### Use a consistent naming scheme within the class

Members seem to have a mix of naming schemes: `buff`, `m_size`, `Log`.  Pick one and stick with it.

### Avoid unnecessary code

In the destructor, we have:

```
buff = nullptr;
m_size = 0;
m_capacity = 0;
Log = 0;
```

These statements are useless clutter, as the object is being destroyed, and the members will not be accessible after this.  A good compiler may elide the code for you, but it can't address the bigger problem, that there's more lines for the human reader to understand.

Similarly, in the move-constructor, we perform most of the destructor actions before calling `swap()`.  It's generally expected that a moved-from object should soon be going out of scope, and perfectly normal to just swap the contents on the assumption that this tidy-up will occur then.

### The `clear()` method leaks memory

We set `buff` to a null pointer without deleting its resource - there's a missing `delete[] buff` there.  It's really worth running the unit tests under Valgrind occasionally to catch stuff like that.

### Don't delete contents on assignment...

...until you have checked for self-assignment.  That's one mistake that copy-and-swap will save you from.

It will help performance if you also check whether the current capacity is already suitable for the new contents.  If it's at least the required size (and not too much bigger - e.g. one or two reallocation steps at most), then you can reduce the work of `new` and `delete` by simply re-using the storage you allocated.

### Use the correct names of functions from `<cmath>`

It appears that your compiler exercises its right to define names in the global namespace as well as in `std`.  But it's not portable to rely on that, so call `std::log` and `std::ceil` by their full names.

### Use a single file

The method definitions need to be visible to the users (as they are templates), so they should be in the header file with the declarations.

Answer (score 9):

### Problems

Your main issue is that your usage of placement new (and manual destructor call) are incorrect and undefined behavior results because the lifespan of objects is inconsistent.

### Code Review

Seems a bit likely to clash with other people

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
```

You have to make these unique include your namespace into the guard. Talking about namespace; add a namespace around your code.

Use of inline is discouraged.

```
    inline unsigned int capacity() const { return m_capacity; }
    inline unsigned int size() const { return m_size; }
    inline bool empty() const { return m_size == 0; }
    inline iterator begin() { return buff; }
    inline iterator end() { return buff + (m_size - 1) * sizeof(T); }
    inline const_iterator c_begin() { return buff; }
    inline const_iterator c_end() { return buff + (m_size - 1) * sizeof(T); }
```

In this context it does not add any real meaning. It was supposed to be a hint to the compiler to inline the code. But it was long since shown that humans are very bad at making this choice and all compilers ignore the hint and only inline when they determine it is useful.

These look wrong.

```
    inline iterator end() { return buff + (m_size - 1) * sizeof(T); }
    inline const_iterator c_end() { return buff + (m_size - 1) * sizeof(T); }
```

There is no need to add `sizeof(T)` in those expressions. When you increment a pointer you are adding by the size of the object that it points at.

Seems like you need const versions of these two (in addition to the non const versions).

```
    T& front();
    T& back();
    T& operator [](unsigned int index);
```

You have move constructors. Why not move insertion.

```
    void pushBack(const T& val);
```

Why not just use a default parameter in the next constructor to implement this version of the constructor?

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector() : 
    m_capacity(0),
    m_size(0),
    Log(0),
    buff(nullptr) {}
```

The order of the initialization list is not relevant.

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int size) : //an argument of 0 leads to a capacity value of 1, distinct from the default ctor
    m_size(size), 
    Log(ceil(log((double)size) / log(2.0))), 
    m_capacity(1 << Log), 
    buff(size ? new T[m_capacity] : nullptr) {}
```

The members are initialized in the order they are declared in class declaration. Changing the order in the initializer list will not change that order. If you turn on your compiler warnings it will tell you this.

As a result these members are not all initialized correctly as some depend on values that have not been initialized yet.

The actual order that will be done is:

```
    m_capacity(1 << Log),                    // Notice here Log is used
                                             // But has not been initialized.
    m_size(size), 
    Log(ceil(log((double)size) / log(2.0))), 
    buff(size ? new T[m_capacity] : nullptr) {}
```

Incorrect usage of placement new.

```
    buff(size ? new T[m_capacity] : nullptr)   // You are calling the constructor of `T` for every object in this array
    ....
    new(buffer + i) T(initial);                // You are over writing an object that has had its constructor called.
```

Placement new can only be used on RAW memory. You are using it here on an already live object (an object that has had its constructor already called). This is undefined behavior.

It would have been more correct to use the assignment operator.

It is a good idea to mark the move constructor as `noexcept`.

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T> && v)
    : m_size(0),
    m_capacity(0),
    buff(nullptr),
    Log(0)
{
    swap(v);
}
```

This allows for certain optimizations by the compiler. Since the only call is to swap() this should be true (traditionally swap is also noexcept).

The Assignment operator does not provide the strong exception guarantee. Also it is not self assignment safe. If you assign this object to itself it will have undefined behavior.

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator =(Vector<T> const& v)
// //not strong exception, but will write a wrapper that makes it strong exception; lowest level -> fastest
{
    delete[] buff;
    buff = nullptr;
    buff = v.m_capacity ? new T[v.m_capacity * sizeof(T)] : nullptr;
    m_size = v.m_size;
    m_capacity = v.m_capacity;
    Log = v.Log;
    std::copy(v.buff, v.buff + m_size-1, buff);
    return *this;
}
```

I see you notice that in your comments. It is trivial to make this exception safe by using the copy and swap idiom (and it has no more overhead than doing it manually). Also the copy and swap idiom is self assignment safe.

Again move operator. Usually mark as `noexcept`. Unfortunately as you call delete you can't do that!

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator =(Vector<T> && v)
{
    delete[] buff; //prep this
    m_size = 0;
    buff = nullptr;
    m_capacity = 0;
    Log = 0;

    swap(v);

    return *this;
}
```

There is no need to do the delete here. Simply do the swap. This will allow you to mark the method `noexcept`. After you have done the swap call clear on the RHS to force the objects in the vector to be destroyed (to mimic the requirements on the std::vector). Let the destructor of the RHS clean up the memory for the vector.

It also adds the opportunity to optimize the usage (as the storage can potentially be re-used).

Extra work being done.

```
template<typename T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete[] buff;

    // Everything below this point is a waste of time.
    // Don't do it.
    // Also assigning null to the pointer can potentially hide errors. When you are debugging.
    buff = nullptr;
    m_size = 0;
    m_capacity = 0;
    Log = 0;
}
```

This call to the destructor will get you into trouble.

```
template<typename T>
void Vector<T>::popBack()
{
    (reinterpret_cast<T*>(buff)[m_size-- - 1]).~T();
}
```

The trouble is that `buff` is a pointer to `T` so when you call delete in the destructor it is going call the destructor for T. By calling it here you have ended the objects life span so calling delete in the destructor is undefined behavior.

I wrote 5 articles about building a vector.

[Vector - Resource Management Allocation](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Vector-ResourceManagementAllocation)
[Vector - Resource Management Copy Swap](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Vector-ResourceManagementCopySwap)
[Vector - Resize](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Vector-Resize)
[Vector - Simple Optimizations](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Vector-SimpleOptimizations)
[Vector - The Other Stuff](https://lokiastari.com/posts/Vector-TheOtherStuff)

Answer (score 7):

### The Type of Your Size Parameters

Currently, you have them as `unsigned int`, but this is often different from `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`.  The most common example in 2018 is that most 64-bit compilers define `unsigned int` as 32 bits wide, which limits your vectors to 4GiB.  It's also possible to imagine implementations with 16- or 24-bit `size_t` but a wider ALU (a 16-bit Windows or DOS program running on an 80386 or better?)  The STL version uses `size_t`, which is 32 bits wide on 32-bit platforms and 64 bits wide on 64-bit platforms.

You will also often find some people who prefer signed to unsigned indices, on the grounds that it's very easy for arithmetic on indices to give you a negative number, and interpreting that as a very large unsigned number will lead to logic errors.  This has a portability issue of its own, in that unsigned overflow and underflow are well-defined but signed overflow and underflow are not, but nearly all real-world implementations use two’s-complement math.  If you want to use signed indices, the type for that is `ptrdiff_t`, which is the type of the result of subtracting one pointer from another.

Microsoft’s preferred solution is `rsize_t`, an optional annex to the C language standard.  This is an unsigned quantity whose upper bit flags it as invalid (that is, a `size_t` that the library is meant to rigorously check for overflow).

### Allocation Size

You choose to allocate blocks as powers of two.  Elsewhere in the comments, when someone asked if it wouldn’t be better to allocate the exact amount of memory requested, I explain the arguments in favor of the power-of-two approach.

However, adding a `.shrink_to_fit()` method gives the client code the ability to decide that wasted memory is a bigger concern for that application than heap fragmentation.  If the application doesn’t call that, they get the default behavior.